# Implement protocol with different variable type

Tags: swift, protocols, swift-protocols

I have protocol named `ResponseProtocol` that contains a variable that is itself protocol `ResponseModel`.
I'm trying to implement it with different conform to the protocol type, but I'm facing with this error:

> Type 'FetchUserResponse' does not conform to protocol
> 'ResponseProtocol'

```
protocol ResponseModel { }

protocol ResponseProtocol {
    var response: ResponseModel
}

struct UserModel: ResponseModel {

}

struct FetchUserResponse: ResponseProtocol {
    var response: UserModel
}
```

my question i, why i'm getting this error?
`UserModel` **is a** `ResponseModel`.

my second question - how can i fix it? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The protocol requirement is `var response: ResponseModel`, not a type which conforms to the protocol.

A better way is an associated type

```
protocol ResponseProtocol {
    associatedtype ResponseType
    var response: ResponseType { get }
}

struct UserModel { }

struct FetchUserResponse: ResponseProtocol {
    typealias ResponseType = UserModel
    var response: UserModel
}
```

Comment: typealias ResponseType = UserModel is not needed. Will be automatically set. I mentioned it in my answer and credited you there.

Answer (score 1):

Please, check the answer of Vadian.
One thing, you don't need to add typealias ResponseType = UserModel.
Like this:

```
protocol ResponseModel {}

protocol ResponseProtocol {
    associatedtype Model: ResponseModel
    var response: Model { get }
}

struct UserModel: ResponseModel {}

struct FetchUserResponse: ResponseProtocol {
    var response: UserModel
}
```

Answer (score 0):

protocol doesn't support inherited variables
you can make your var response as ResponseModel and cast it in your usage

Answer (score 0):

your response var needs to be a ResponseModel

```
struct FetchUserResponse: ResponseProtocol {
    var response: ResponseModel
}
```

but you can assign a UserModel to response based on polymorphism concept

```
var object = FetchUserResponse(response: UserModel())
```